# Specs2 for parsing a file using Configfactory.parseString Scala

Tags: scala, specifications, specs2

I am trying to write a specification using specs2 to read from a config file and parse it in key value pairs I am new to both Specification and SCALA so I don't know  which way I am heading, this is what I have written so far with the help of an example from internet. I need to know how will I be able to achieve the specifications to read and parse the file data.

I have just one method parseConfig

```
   @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
  class ConfigParserTest extends Specification {
 "ConfigParserTest" should {
    "parseConfig" in {
      ok
    }

    "parseConfig" in {
      val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
        """timeUnit: MILLISECONDS,
          |sensors: {
          |   probes: {
          |     simone : {
          |       class: parser.ConfigParser,
          |       config: {}
          |     }
          |   }
          |}
        """.stripMargin)
      ok
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the object returned by the `ConfigFactory`? Assuming it is a case class like `Configuration` you can simply use the equality matcher:

```
"parseConfig" in {
   val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(...)

   config === 
     Configuration(timeUnit = Milliseconds,
       sensors = Sensors(
         probes = Probes(
           klass = ConfigParser
           config = Nil
         )
       )
     )
}
```